# How to get actual html element from Kendo MVVM data-bind function call

Tags: javascript, kendo-mvvm

In my html template i used :

```
<div class="h-line" data-bind="style:{width:getWidth(this)}"> <hr /> </div>
```

In my viewModel i tried to get this element like this way :

```
getWidth: function (element) {
    console.log("Element", element);
    return ($("#preview-app").width()) + "px";
}
```

But i can't get the caller element in my `console.log("Element", element)`. Is there any way to get caller element using this model function ?

Comment: what is element in this scenario?

Comment: @lcepickl, I want to get `<div class="h-line" data-bind="style:{width:getWidth(this)}"> <hr /> </div>` in `console.log()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way >

JS :

```
getWidth: function () {
    return ($(".h-line").[0].offsetWidth) + "px";
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="h-line" data-bind="style:{width:getWidth}"> <hr /> </div>
```

Hope it will help.